# Postgresql Query is taking over 30s, Failing on Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have two tables (tb_accounts and tb_similar_accounts) in my PostgreSQL database.

Each record in `tb_accounts` has a unique `id` field.

[image: tb_accounts has unique id]

And in `tb_similar_accounts` table, we store the relationships between accounts. We have around 10 million records in this table.

[image]

I get around 1000~4000 accounts in one of my API endpoints, and I want to get all the links from `tb_similar_accounts`

```
const ids_str = `${ids.map((id) => `('${id}')`).join(`,`)}`;

const pgQuery = `
    SELECT account_1 as source, account_2 as target, strength as weight FROM tb_similar_accounts 
    WHERE account_1 = ANY (VALUES ${ids_str}) AND account_2 = ANY (VALUES ${ids_str})
    ORDER BY strength DESC
    LIMIT 10000
`;

const { rows: visEdges } = await pgClient.query(pgQuery);
```

This is what I'm doing here, but it's taking too much time. It takes over 30 seconds so it's failing on the Heroku server.

```
Limit  (cost=296527.60..297597.60 rows=10000 width=30) (actual time=25075.977..25078.602 rows=10000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=19 read=121634
  I/O Timings: read=22104.502
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=296527.60..297967.40 rows=13456 width=30) (actual time=25075.975..25080.332 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 1
        Workers Launched: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=110 read=244343
        I/O Timings: read=44196.556
        ->  Sort  (cost=295527.60..295534.33 rows=13456 width=30) (actual time=25070.720..25071.022 rows=5546 loops=2)
              Sort Key: tb_similar_accounts.strength DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 1550kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 1550kB
              Buffers: shared hit=110 read=244343
              I/O Timings: read=44196.556
              ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=5.74..295343.04 rows=13456 width=30) (actual time=1040.173..25060.553 rows=38449 loops=2)
                    Hash Cond: (tb_similar_accounts.account_1 = "*VALUES*".column1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=63 read=244343
                    I/O Timings: read=44196.556
                    ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=2.87..295096.26 rows=381936 width=30) (actual time=2.197..25039.864 rows=80874 loops=2)
                          Hash Cond: (tb_similar_accounts.account_2 = "*VALUES*_1".column1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=33 read=244343
                          I/O Timings: read=44196.556
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tb_similar_accounts  (cost=0.00..286491.44 rows=14038480 width=30) (actual time=0.032..23394.824 rows=11932708 loops=2)
                                Buffers: shared hit=33 read=244343
                                I/O Timings: read=44196.556
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.44..1.44 rows=410 width=32) (actual time=0.241..0.242 rows=410 loops=2)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 26kB
                                ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*_1"  (cost=0.00..1.44 rows=410 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.153 rows=410 loops=2)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.44..1.44 rows=410 width=32) (actual time=0.198..0.198 rows=410 loops=2)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 26kB
                          ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..1.44 rows=410 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.113 rows=410 loops=2)
Planning Time: 3.522 ms
Execution Time: 25081.725 ms
```

This is for 410 accounts and takes around 25 seconds.

Is there any way to improve this query? (I'm using Node.js and `pg` module.)

Comment: Is `tb_similar_accounts` a view maybe? I don't understand where the join comes from. There is no join in the query have show us.

Comment: I'm taking account ids from the frontend and getting links from them.

Comment: You are sequentially scanning 12M records twice in `tb_similar_accounts`.  That takes time.  You may be able to avoid that by indexing `account_1` and `account_2` separately on tha ttable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  The `=ANY` was rewritten into a join.  Note that one table of the join is a `Values Scan`

Comment: Other than getting faster IO, perhaps try an index on `(account_1, account_2, strength)`

Answer (score 0):

Check if both your tables are indexed properly i.e. try to build index on the columns which are used in joining two tables.